# My unit was broken into after uhaul put a non payment lock on it, so isn't it now their responsibility?

Tags: rental-property, property, arizona

I'm in Arizona and like my question says they put a non payment lock on my unit (payroll messed up at my job) and I said I had my own insurance so I didn't take theirs, but I never brought them my proof of insurance because it is slipped my mind and who thinks you would need to do that it's supposed to be secure. They're saying it's my responsibility now to cover it despite the fact I couldn't even access my unit when the break in took place and I can't even access the unit until tomorrow to check what was stolen because the property manager has the day off. What should they have done and what should I be doing? I was told the onus is on them but I have my doubts.

Comment: Which responsibility to "cover it" are you speaking of? Do you mean the fact that the person who broke in destroyed their structure, or are you talking about the damage to your property?

Answer (score 5):

They almost surely have no liability to you for the loss of, or damage to, your property, as the standard rental agreement that you signed almost certainly relieves them of this responsibility. If you have insurance (even though you didn't provide them with proof of insurance) that would probably cover your loses. If not, you are probably just screwed and have no recourse.